# Checking hash and passwords with a wordlist, more efficient

Tags: python, performance, cryptography, hashcode

I have done a small code in which with a wordlist (out68.lst) I get the passwords from the hashes in the file 'shadow3'.

```
import crypt
import string
import itertools
import datetime

dir = "shadow3"                          #File that contains hashes and users
file = open(dir, 'r').readlines()

username = []
hashed = []
k=0


for x in file:
    usr, hshd, wtf, iss, this, thing, here, doing, example = x.split(':')
    username.append(usr)
    hashed.append(hshd)
#Loop in order to split the data in the file and store it in username and hashed

grupo1=open('out68.lst','r').readlines()
long=len(grupo1)
print(long)
for y in grupo1:    #Loop in order to go through all the possible words available
  c = 0
  y=y.rstrip('\n')
  y=y.capitalize()
  k = k+1
  if k==(long//100):
    print('1%')
  if k==(long//10):
    print('10%')
  if k==(long//5):
    print('20%')
  if k==(3*long//10):
    print('30%')
  if k==(4*long//10):     #Just to check the progress
    print('40%')
  if k==(5*long//10):
    print('50%')
  if k==(6*long//10):
    print('60%')
  if k==(7*long//10):
    print('70%')
  if k==(8*long//10):
    print('80%')
  if k==(9*long//10):
    print('90%')


  for x in hashed:
      rehashed = crypt.crypt(y, x) #Hash verification f(passwor+hash)=hash?
      if rehashed == x:
          print('La contraseña del usuario ' + username[c] + ' es ' + y)
      c = c + 1
```

It does work but depending on the size of the files, it can last now from 30 minutes to 6 hours.  So I am asking if there is any way to improve the performance, by paralelization, or GPU processing (but I have no idea about this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Run the code through at least one linter such as flake8 or pycodestyle to produce more idiomatic code.
- Don't read all the lines into a variable before starting processing - this will slow things down and use much more memory than necessary for large files. Instead you can use [`for line in file.readlines()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478697/96588).
- You are doing ten calculations in order to run a single print statement. Either get rid of them or do something simpler like `print("{}/{} complete".format(k, long))`.
- If you *know* `y` has exactly one newline at the end you can do `y[:-1]` instead of `y.rstrip('\n')`.
- Capitalizing each word is expensive. Avoid it if at all possible.
- If you don't need a bunch of the fields in an input file add a limit to your `split()` and mark the last stuff as discarded by using the `_` variable. For example: `usr, hshd, _ = x.split(':', 3)`
- Rather than keeping track of `k` manually you can just do `for k, y in enumerate(grupo1)`.
- Rather than having a list of usernames and a list of their hashed passwords, a `Dict[str, str]` of username to hash should be easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure you close files you open. This can be easily achieved using the [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) keyword:

```
file_name = "shadow3"
with open(file_name) as file:
    usernames, hashed_passwords = [], []
    for line in file:
        username, hashed_password, *_ = line.split(':')
        usernames.append(username)
        hashed_passwords.append(hashed_password)
```

Calling a file `dir` is just setting yourself up for trouble later. I also used the [advanced tuple assignment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) by using `*` to assign the rest of the line to the unused variable `_` (a customary name for unused variables).

Note that `open` opens a file in read-only mode by default, so `'r'` is implicitly used.

---

Whenever you want to iterate over an iterable but also need a counter, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) and whenever you want to iterate over two iterables in tandem, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open('out68.lst') as group:
    length = len(group)
    for k, password in enumerate(group):
        password = password.rstrip('\n').capitalize()

        if k == length // 100 or k % (length // 10) == 0:
            print(f"{k / length:.%}")
        for username, hashed_password in zip(usernames, hashed_passwords):
            if crypt.crypt(password, hashed_password) == hashed_password:
                print(f'La contraseña del usuario {username} es {password}')
```

Here I also used modular arithmetic to cut down your special cases for ten percent increments, used the new [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) formatting.

---

You might want to add some functionality where you save username password pairs if you have found some and remove them from the `usernames` and `hashed_passwords` lists so you don't keep on checking them once you found the password. To do this efficiently it might be necessary to change your data format to `{username: hashed_password}` and `{username: password}` for the yet to find and already found usernames.

```
file_name = "shadow3"
users = {}
with open(file_name) as file:
    for line in file:
        username, hashed_password, *_ = line.split(':')
        users[username] = hashed_password

cracked_users = {}
with open('out68.lst') as group:
    length = len(group)
    for k, password in enumerate(group):
        password = password.rstrip('\n').capitalize()
        if k == length // 100 or k % (length // 10) == 0:
            print(f"{k / length:.%}")
        if not users:
             print("Cracked all passwords")
             break
        for username, hashed_password in users.items():
            if crypt.crypt(password, hashed_password) == hashed_password:
                print(f'La contraseña del usuario {username} es {password}')
                cracked_users[username] = password
                del users[username]
```

---

In general, don't be afraid of giving your variables clear names. If it is a username, call it `username`, not `usr`. If it is a hashed password, call it `hashed_password`, not `hshd`.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I had problems changing the format because of the input file I think so I  made this   `  for x in hashed:
      rehashed = crypt.crypt(y, x)
      if rehashed == x:
          print('La contraseña del usuario ' + username[c] + ' es ' + y)
          del hashed[c]
          del username[c]
      c = c + 1`  that this should work, right?